# GetHostAddresses timeout

Tags: windows

When calling `Dns.GetHostAddresses("an_hostname_that_does_not_exist");` on windows 10 I get a 30 seconds blocking call until getting an exception (when the hostname does not exist). On windows 2019 it is more in the 10 seconds range and on windows server 2012 it is less than 1 second.

Is there a way to configure the duration of the timeout when calling `gethostbyname` (mainly for Windows 2019) ?

NB : I can not change the call to Dns.GetHostAddresses but I can change any configuration on the client machine

NB : `Dns.GetHostAddresses` looks to ultimately resolve to the below call.

```
[DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static extern IntPtr gethostbyname([In] string host);
```

NB : I found that but it looks to be for old windows version and I don't have anything in my registry : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc977482(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN